# UploadedFile::getInstanceByName return null

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I’m learning to play with yii2 and so I’m following a tutorial when I do the vardump the result I get is null but I should get a result like the photo someone knows what I’m doing wrong?
Thank you!

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Video();

        $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('video');

        var_dump($file);
        exit;

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['update', 'video_id' => $model->video_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

View:

```
<?php $form = \yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm::begin([
            'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']
        ]) ?>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model) ?>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
            Select File
            <input type="file" id="videoFile" name="video">
        </button>
        <?php \yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

model:

```
public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
    {
        $isInsert = $this->isNewRecord;
        if ($isInsert) {
            $this->video_id = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(8);
            $this->title = $this->video-> name;
            $this->video_name = $this->video->name;
        }
        $saved = parent::save($runValidation, $attributeNames);
        if (!$saved) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($isInsert) {
            $videoPath = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/storage/videos/' . $this->video_id . '.mp4');
            if (!is_dir(dirname($videoPath))) {
                FileHelper::createDirectory(dirname($videoPath));
            }
            $this->video->saveAs($videoPath);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: According to your code, you are trying dump the file before uploading. Move it after post request is received by controller.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add following line at top:

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile; 

$file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('video');

$newFileName = rand() . '.' . $file->extension;

$file->saveAs($uploadPath . '/' . $newFileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of the file. You need to go to php.ini and increase the maximum post size where you find it.

You can also, without modifying, trying to attach a file not bigger than 40mb